# How can i print arraylist from class AsyncTask?

Tags: android, arraylist

I want to print an `ArrayList`. I have receive value arraylist from class `AsyncTask`, in `MainActivity`, I have value ArrayList, but when I print ArrayList, my app is not working. Please help me!

*MainActivity*

```
{
        executeLoadProduct();
        arraylistgroup = new ArrayList<String>();
        arraylistgroup=TaskLoadProductGroup.getvaluearraylist();

        String[] mStringArray = new String[arraylistgroup.size()];
        mStringArray = arraylistgroup.toArray(mStringArray);

        for (int i = 0; i < mStringArray.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("string is2" + (String) mStringArray[i]);
        }
```

*executeLoadProduct*

```
 private void executeLoadProduct() {
            // execute task load product
            loadProductGroup = new TaskLoadProductGroup(MainActivity.this);
            loadProductGroup.execute();
        }
```

*AsyncTask*

```
public class TaskLoadProductGroup extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<String>> {
    private ActionBarActivity actionBarActivity;
    private Context context;
    private static ArrayList<String> arrayListgroup;

    public TaskLoadProductGroup(ActionBarActivity actionBarActivity) {
        this.actionBarActivity = actionBarActivity;
        this.context = actionBarActivity.getApplicationContext();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        ///show progress loading

        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String... url) {
        ArrayList<String> listProductgroup = null;
        try {
            Server server = new Server();
            ResListProduct resListProduct = server.getListProducts(context);

            //init list item for listview home product
            listProductgroup = initItemProduct(resListProduct);

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return listProductgroup;
    }

    public static ArrayList<String> initItemProduct(ResListProduct rsProduct) {
        List<GroupProduct> groups = rsProduct.getGroups();
        arrayListgroup = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (GroupProduct group : groups) {
            // add header group
            String s = group.getName();
            arrayListgroup.add(s);          
        }
        getvaluearraylist();
        // getVarialty();
        return arrayListgroup;
    }

    public static ArrayList<String> getvaluearraylist()
    {
        return arrayListgroup;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> listProductgroup) {
        super.onPostExecute(listProductgroup);      
    }

}
```

Comment: Is this what you tried in `mainactivity.java` to print your array ?

Comment: i want to print arrayListgroup from class TaskLoadProductGroup .

Comment: Then what happened when you try to print that from doInBackground ? Are you trying to print using Log class or print on device's screen ?

Comment: i am trying to print using Log class

Comment: OK see my answer, If you got any problem then comment fast, because I am getting in leave now..

Comment: i have comment my problem, can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't identify why are you doing so complex code to print the `ArrayList`. You can just print that inside `onPostExecute` method like this,

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> listProductgroup) {
 super.onPostExecute(listProductgroup);   

     for (String value : listProductgroup){
         Log.d("myTag", value);
        }
 }
```

**OR**

Use `loadProductGroup.execute().get()` method, but remember this will freeze your UI.

Comment: because in Mainactivity, i use value listProductgroup for some function. in fist, i want to print it in  Mainactivity. please help me?

Comment: You can assign that listProductgroup in your field like `arraylistgroup = listProductgroup` inside onPostExecute, Then print that variable..

Comment: @tonyHoang You can also use [get](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get()) method as well